# Typesafe activator not installing

Tags: typesafe-activator

I want to install typesafe activator. I have installed jdk 7 and have path and java_home variable to correct location.
path :

```
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin

Java_Home
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin
```

Activator.bat opens and disappears. I dont know what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to mention the path of the Typesafe activator folder in that line too. First download the Typesafe Activator and unzip the folder into a drive ("c:/" preferred). Now copy the link of that folder : (look like this : `C:\activator-1.2.8` ) should be included into the path you have mentioned like the jdk path followed by a ";" semi colon.

Sample:

```
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\activator-1.2.8
```

After Restart you can check installation by simply typing "activator" in the command line.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> You need to mention the path of the Typesafe activator folder in that
>   line too. First download the Typesafe Activator and unzip the folder
>   into a drive ("c:/" preferred). Now copy the link of that folder :
>   (look like this : C:\activator-1.2.8 ) should be included into the
>   path you have mentioned like the jdk path followed by a ";" semi
>   colon.
>
> Sample:
>
> PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;C:\activator-1.2.8
>
> After Restart you can check installation by simply typing "activator"
>   in the command line.
>
> Thanks!

I have the same error here now and followed your steps but when I try "activator" on prompt, it seems to execute the activator.bat file and retrieve me the same error log.

Is there anything that must be installed before. Can it be in any ways a Proxy trouble?

In time: My .sbt folder is almost empty. There is only a folder with the error log inside.

**UPDATE**

after trying for a while, i've come with a solution. The activator command requires the proxy to set. Didn't try to do this before 'cause I'm new in the company and didn't had full permission. Now, when use the console command:

> set HTTP_PROXY=http://**host**:**port**

It just worked fine.

Hope it helps!